# How to pass value of DataList item to variable in aspx

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio

I have a `Datalist` in `updatepanel` that gets populated on onchange of a drop down list. That Drop down list displays departments. `DataList` shows sections of selected department. 
Under each section, we have multiple services. I want those services to be displayed in the form of radio button. 
So it should work like this :

User selects department from drop down list. Ajax call is made and shows sections of selected department. On clicking any section, it must show services in that particular section.

I can handle show/hide when user will be click on section.

I can get dataList item value in radio button like this

```
<input type="radio" name="SectionsRadioGroup" value="<%# Eval("Section") %>" /> <%# Eval("Section") %>
```

Actually, i want the value of "Section" in a variable, like this :

```
<% Dim sectionVariable As String = Eval("Section") %>
```

But i am getting error:

> Databinding methods such as eval() xpath() and bind() can only be used
>   in the context of a databound

How can i pass value of datalist item to variable in aspx file.

Thanking You..

Answer (score 0):

You can access `protected` (and `public`) properties/fields from the codebehind file in an ASPX file.

Make `SectionVariable` a protected property in codehind, and assign the value.

Then you can access it from ASPX using `<%= SectionVariable %>`.

You cannot use `Eval()` outside a databound context, as the error says.

Comment: I have this section value in loop coming from database.

Comment: I want to parse its value bcuz it is comma separated and display 2 radio buttons

Comment: Update your question with the missing bits and pieces then, and specify what the problem is, and some sample input and desired output.